# Vector space , topology and semi norm

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

This question was asked in my lecture of topology and I need help in solving this problem.

> Question: Let X be a vector space, and let ||.|| be a semi-norm on X. Show that if the topology defined by ||.|| is hausdorff then ||.|| is a norm.

Attempt: I am not really sure on how can I prove this result. I have studied general topology but I am unable to solve this question.

Can you please help me solve this question?

Comment: I don't think this is true. For example, $\Bbb{R}^2$ with the seminorm $\|(x,y)\| = |x|$ is separable (e.g. $\Bbb{Q}\times \{0\}$ is a countable dense subset) but $\|\cdot\|$ is not a norm.

Comment: @mechanodroid Maybe there is a confusion with Hausdorff? In French, the word *séparé* ("separated") is used for Hausdorff. Since OP is from South America, I wouldn't be surprised that Hausdorff would translate into a word that is really close to "separable" in OP's language (presumably Spanish or Portuguese, which are close to French)

Comment: @Didier Great observation! You are right!

Answer (score 0):

If $||x|| = 0$ then any open ball around $x$ contains $0$ and any open ball around $0$ contains $x$. So $x$ and $0$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets since they would contain open balls around the two points, which must also be disjoint. So if $X$ is Hausdorff (or even $T_0$) then $x = 0$ for any such $x$, that is to say the semi-norm is a norm.